# Erro no git: "remote: Repository not found. "

Tags: git, github, git-remote

Toda vez que eu tento executar o comando `git push -u origin master`, o Git gera um erro de repositório não encontrado.

Eu segui certinho o passo a passo que está escrito no GitHub. Abaixo está tudo o que eu fiz até mandar o `push` para vocês verem e tentarem me ajudar:

- criei um repositório privado no GitHub sem o arquivo `readme.md`
- criei uma pasta no meu computador
- abri o Git nela
- digitei os seguintes comandos:

  ```
  echo "# test-git" >> README.md
  git init
  git add README.md
  git commit -m "first commit"
  git remote add origin https://github.com/usuario-do-git/nome-do-repositorio.git
  git push -u origin master
  ```

Logo em seguida o seguinte erro é gerado:

> remote: Repository not found.

Uma amiga minha seguiu esses passos e não obteve este erro, ao contrário, correu tudo certo para ela. Já tentei de tudo, excluí até a conta e criei de novo, e novamente repeti todos os passos.

O que estou fazendo de errado para ser lançado este erro ?

Comment: Teste em vez de "master" por "main"... acredito eu que  possa ser isso...   git push -u origin main

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro verifique se o repositório remoto já está sendo identificado com o comando `git remote -v`. Se ele não estiver listado, vincule o repositório remoto ao seu repositório local com o comando `git remote add origin git@github.com:leocomelli/curso-git.git`.
Repare que na sua tentativa você não utiliza o trecho `git@github.com:`. Adicione este trecho na tentativa e veja se dá certo.